# WebAssembly via d8.exe

Tags: embedded-v8, webassembly

*I posted this question here because I asked this question as part of another post, but found the solution before anyone answered it. Just want to share my findings.*

I decided to try `d8.exe` only because I want to play around with WebAssembly don't feel like installing Chrome Canary. Still trying to figure out how to load `.wasm` file into `d8.exe` since I can't use `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` to read the binary files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My findings:

- Enable WebAssembly in `d8.exe` with `--expose_wasm` flag.
- Use [binaryen](https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen) to convert hand-written `.wast` to `.wasm`.
- Use [binaryen.js](https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen/blob/master/bin/binaryen.js) to compile string into `wasm` inside `d8.exe`.
- Read `.wasm` with `readbuffer`.
- WebAssembly's JavaScript API can be found in https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/JS.md